# Update large sqlite database in chunks

Tags: python, memory, sqlite, sql-update

I have a sqlite database (appr. 11 GB) that has multiple tables including the tables `distance` and `vertices`. The table `distance` is pretty large (120 mio rows), `vertices` is smaller (15 000 rows). I want to use sqlite3 in python to update one column of `distance` by values of another column in `vertices`. The table vertices has an index on column `cat` and another index on `orig_cat`.

What I am doing:

```
import sqlite3
db_path='path/to/db.db'

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''UPDATE distance SET 
                from_orig_v = (SELECT orig_cat FROM vertices WHERE cat=distance.source)''')
```

However running that update statement on such a large database, causes a memory error. The memory usage is increasing steadily until it crashes. I am looking for advise to perform such a large update statement without running out of memory? Maybe processing the update in chunks (i.e. rows of `distance` table) and committing after e.g. 1000 updates to free memory? How would that be done in python/sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to update chunks with statements like this:

```sql
UPDATE distance SET ... WHERE rowid BETWEEN 100000 AND 200000;
```

You don't need to use multiple transactions; the only thing that actually must be kept in memory is the list of rows to be updated in a single statement.
(In theory, when memory runs out, you should get an appropriate error message. In practice, some OSes [overcommit memory](https://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html) and don't tell the application about it until it's too late.)

Comment: I'm thinking about using this as a solution to a similar problem. Do you have any ideas on why SQLite3 crashes when updating a big database?